# Android Gridview not obeying vertical spacing

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-gridview, universal-image-loader

My code produces gridview with only horizontal spacing but no vertical spacing. Can't find the problem even after searching google. I only get the vertical spacing if i add padding to the imageview, but it doesn't give me the required spacing. Here is my code, i use universal image loader:

```
public PhotoGridFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the individual image size in the grid and the grid image spacing
    mImageThumbSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_size);
    mImageThumbSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_spacing);

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2)
    .considerExifParams(true)
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();

    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());

    if(((MainActivity)getActivity()).isRunningFirstTime) {

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_grid_fragment, container, false);
    final GridView mGridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(ImageLoader.getInstance(), false, true));

    // This listener is used to get the final width of the GridView and then calculate the
    // number of columns and the width of each column. The width of each column is variable
    // as the GridView has stretchMode=columnWidth. The column width is used to set the height
    // of each view so we get nice square thumbnails.
    mGridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    if (mAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                        final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(
                                mGridView.getWidth() / (mImageThumbSize + mImageThumbSpacing));
                        if (numColumns > 0) {
                            final int columnWidth =
                                    (mGridView.getWidth() / numColumns) - mImageThumbSpacing;
                            columnNum = numColumns;
                            mAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                            mAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);
                            if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
                                mGridView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                            } else {
                                mGridView.getViewTreeObserver()
                                        .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@TargetApi(VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    final Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), PhotoDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(PhotoDetailActivity.EXTRA_IMAGE, (photoIds[position - columnNum]));
    if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
        // makeThumbnailScaleUpAnimation() looks kind of ugly here as the loading spinner may
        // show plus the thumbnail image in GridView is cropped. so using
        // makeScaleUpAnimation() instead.
        ActivityOptions options =
                ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        getActivity().startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
    } else {
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

public int getCurTab() {
    return getArguments().getInt(CURRENT_TAB);
}

public static PhotoGridFragment newInstance(int position, int curTab) {
    PhotoGridFragment photoGrid = new PhotoGridFragment();
    Bundle categoryId = new Bundle();
    categoryId.putInt(CATEGORY_ID, position);
    categoryId.putInt(CURRENT_TAB, curTab);
    photoGrid.setArguments(categoryId);
    return photoGrid;
}


/**
 * The main adapter that backs the GridView. This is fairly standard except the number of
 * columns in the GridView is used to create a fake top row of empty views as we use a
 * transparent ActionBar and don't want the real top row of images to start off covered by it.
 */
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private GridView.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // If columns have yet to be determined, return no items
        if (getNumColumns() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        // Size + number of columns for top empty row
        return photoIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return photoIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        } else { // Otherwise re-use the converted view
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        if ((imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) 
                || (imageView.getLayoutParams().width != mItemHeight))
            {
                imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
            }

        // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
        // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
        ImageLoader.getInstance()
        .displayImage(photoIds[position], imageView, options);
        return imageView;
        //END_INCLUDE(load_gridview_item)
    }

    /**
     * Sets the item height. Useful for when we know the column width so the height can be set
     * to match.
     *
     * @param height
     */
    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams =
                new GridView.LayoutParams(mItemHeight, mItemHeight);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }
}
```

}

Gridview xml:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnWidth="@dimen/image_thumbnail_size"
android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/image_thumbnail_spacing"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:listSelector="@drawable/photogrid_list_selector" />
```

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case, it was because I hadn't specified columnWidth. I was relying on the size of the items in the column to determine the columnWidth. Surprisingly, numColumns="auto_fit" doesn't work well with that.

Answer (score 3):

Spent 6 hours trying to find the problem. Now i have the solution. The problem was the 1dp spacing was not showing on ldpi devices but was showing on mdpi, xhdpi, etc. I just created a "values-ldpi" folder and create a dimens.xml folder then added the dimension image_thumbnail_spacing and assigned it to 2dp and its working now. Thanks